# telerik RadHTMLPlaceHolder custom jquery tooltip partially visible

Tags: jquery, silverlight, telerik, tiptip

I am using the `RadHTMLPlaceHolder` in silverlight out-of-browser application. Problem is, my [jquery tooltip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin) is used and passed through html source to the `RadHTMLPlaceHolder` can only be seen partially because of other grid elements.

```
<Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="auto"  Height="auto" 
           BorderBrush="#000000" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
     <telerik:RadHtmlPlaceholder  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="htmlSource" />
</Border>
```

What can be the solution? `Canvas.zindex` is also not working.